Copy SPO items with version history
Is there a way to copy the list items to another list(similar list) along with version history using power automate.
I have complete copying the list items successfully, but I did not get version history. Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Unfortunately, Power Automate does not support copying list items along with their version history to another list. Power Automate can copy list items, but it doesn't have the capability to include version history in the process.
The version history of list items is tied to the specific SharePoint list and isn’t accessible through Power Automate's standard actions.

There is only PowerShell or C# in SharePoint, there is also an option to copy via MS SQL, but I do not know it.

C# -
https://mickdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/10/copying-list-items-with-metadata.html
PowerShell -
https://lazyadmin.nl/it/copy-sharepoint-list-items-to-another-list-with-powershell-and-pnp/

